# Unable to create process using '"c:\bld\scrapy_1564674375870\_h_env\python.exe"

Tags: python, scrapy, anaconda

I'm trying to install Scrapy with Anaconda

After downloading scrapy by command `conda install -c conda-forge scrapy`
and then giving the path of Anaconda/Scripts to environmental variables, I'm getting following error:

```
    C:\Users\Rodzice.Mateusz-PC>scrapy
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\bld\scrapy_1564674375870\_h_env\python.exe"  "C:\Users\Rodzice.Mateusz-PC\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy.exe"
```

I'm getting this error in both cmd and Anaconda

Comment: Did you find how to solve this? I've encountered also this error. Using last Anaconda and installing scrapy with `conda install -c conda-forge scrapy`
btw I found this line `bld\scrapy_1564674375870` on my computer in theese files:
`d:\anaconda3\pkgs\scrapy-1.7.3-py37h6538335_0\info\recipe\meta.yaml`

`d:\anaconda3\pkgs\scrapy-1.7.3-py37h6538335_0\Scripts\scrapy.exe`

`d:\anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy.exe`

Answer (score 8):

```
python -m scrapy startproject papa
```

It works

I don't know why :)

Comment: The problem has been submitted & acknowledged as an issue on the Scrapy feedstock repo page:
https://github.com/conda-forge/scrapy-feedstock/issues/37


One of the Scrapy developers had this to say:
`My assumption is - missing scrapy entry_point in /recipe/info/meta.yaml and rest of conda-forge package that built based on this /meta.yaml causing this error.`

Answer (score 6):

Force reinstalling scrapy using pip solved the problem.

```
pip install --force-reinstall scrapy
```

Answer (score 3):

All the comments here helped me to solve this issue. However, I'm listing here the steps that I followed.

- Uninstalled scrapy using conda uninstall scrapy (You can verify this using conda list command)
- Installed scrapy again using pip install --force-reinstall scrapy

Comment: `conda uninstall scrapy` and `pip install scrapy` without the "--force-reinstall" option worked for me. With the option, I received a "Cannot uninstall 'functools32'" error.

Answer (score 2):

The path I followed:

1. Uninstalled scrapy - 'conda uninstall scrapy'
2. 'pip install scrapy'

It works for me

Comment: This is really similiar to at least two answers... Is there any further info you could provide?

Answer (score 1):

use anaconda prompt as administrator its work for me. 
run anaconda as administrator and pip install scrapy

Comment: Yeah, that helped, maybe admin is not even necessary (but I've run anaconda promt as admin, just in case), first uninstalled with `conda install -c conda-forge scrapy`, then reinstalled with `pip install scrapy`

Comment: thats happen because you install anaconda for “Just Me” if you install anaconda for all users (which requires Windows Administrator privileges) then its work from anaconda prompt without run as admin

Comment: I just did not try it without admin, but suppose it would work, cause I've installed anaconda for everyone with admin priveleges, for all users.

Answer (score 1):

Installing/Uninstalling/Reinstalling Conda/Scrapy/PIP did not work for me.

I tried the following...

**Step 1.** I did a search on 'd:\bld\scrapy_1584555997548_h_env\python.exe' on all the anaconda files.

**Step 2.** Got the following results:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\scrapy-2.0.1-py37hc8dfbb8_0\info\recipe\meta.yaml (1 hit)
Line 15:     script: D:\bld\scrapy_1584555997548\_h_env\python.exe -m pip install . --no-deps

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\scrapy-2.0.1-py37hc8dfbb8_0\Scripts\scrapy.exe (1 hit)
Line 688: </assembly>XXPADDINGPADDINGXXPAD
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy.exe (1 hit)
Line 688: </assembly>DINGPADDINGXXPAD
```

**Step 3.** 
Replaced instances of **d:\bld\scrapy_1584555997548_h_env\python.exe** with 
    **C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe**

**Step 4.** Ran scrapy on the anaconda prompt, and it got executed without throwing 
    any errors!!!

Would be awesome if someone could explain why this worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
I fixed it by:

1. Uninstalling Anaconda in Add/Remove Programs
2. Installing it again but this time selecting "Install for All Users"

(Note: Just re-installing Anaconda again, and selecting "All Users" didn't work. I HAD to first remove it via Add/Remove programs.)

Then when I ran Anaconda Prompt (as Administrator) it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried all these tips, but to no avail.

So I removed the scrapy package and did a new installation, but in the "base" environment, it worked perfectly.